# Python program misbehavior when spawning processes from a py2exe file

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, py2exe

My dad is working on a program that, among others, needs to ping a machine. It is multithreaded and he built a ping method that's be called from any one of the threads, when needed:

```
def ping_cmd(ip):
    if hasattr(sys.stderr, "fileno"):
        nstderr = sys.stderr
    elif hasattr(sys.stderr, "_file") and hasattr(sys.stderr._file, "fileno"):
        nstderr = sys.stderr._file
    else:
        nstderrPath = "nul"
        nstderr = file(nstderrPath, "a")

    p = subprocess.Popen("ping -n 1 %s" % ip,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=nstderr,
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell=True
                        )
    result = p.communicate()[0]
    ...
```

The if-else block statements are written as advised here:
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2ExeSubprocessInteractions

The code works fine when run from the command line using python (he tested it, threads made several pings, no errors), but what my dad needs is to make it a windows executable, so when he's using **py2exe** the following bizzare behavior occurs:
first time after this method is called the program exits, even though the main thread is an infinite loop.

It is compiled as a GUI application even though it doesn't have an interface because that easily makes the process run in background, I don't know if that's the best way to achieve this, but maybe it's useful.

I've never used py2exe because most of my work is on linux machines, but it seems to me it has something to do with this combination of mixing threads with spawning processes when compiling with py2exe.

py2exe specific options for compiling the code:

```
setup(
options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 1,
                      "optimize": 2,
                      "ascii": 1,
                      "bundle_files": 1,
                      "includes": ["encodings", "encodings.*"],
                      "packages": ["encodings"]}},
zipfile = None,
name    = "Monit",
windows = ['Monit.py'],
)
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of error message? There's not really any way to know what's happening unless there is some kind of error.

Comment: Is this code running in the main thread, or in one of the background threads? If the former, it's likely just that some exception propagates outside the infinite loop. In that case, there ought to be an exception traceback printed to stderr, unless there's a handler outside the loop that eats the exception. If the latter, that shouldn't be possible unless the process exits with a Windows structured exception (rough equivalent to segfault or other signal), which should pop up a window about abnormal process exit.

Comment: For the edit: As your linked page explains, that's only needed for GUI apps, not console apps. So, is the program actually a GUI app, is it a console app that he's `py2exe`ing as a GUI (`pythonw`) app, or is it a console app that he's doing stuff in that doesn't need to be done?

Comment: Also, in "first time after this method is called the program exits"… what exactly is the timing? Does the program exit before the method can do its thing? Or half-way through the method? Or after it returns? Or not until the second time you try to call it?

Comment: Answers to the comments: the application is compiled as a GUI application even though it doesn't have an interface because this way it can run in the background. The program exists after finishing running the method, what's in the method seems not to be relevant, I asked him to take everything off and return a hardcoded string and it still happened. He examined the stderr, even put some debugging code and it seems like the method ends gracefully before the program exits